# JavaScript - Cannot understand where it is being passed

Tags: javascript, function

The following code is supposed to log the correct number of button pressed. And it is supposedly does.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Button ' + i));
  btn.addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
    return function() { console.log(i); };
  })(i)); //line 4!
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

What I don't get is what is the use of (i) on the line 4.
It doesn't seem to pass anywhere as for me. 
Tell me please what to read so I could understand this.

Comment: It's [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) because in javascript loops don't introduce new scope only functions does, so you need one of those to create new scope with i variable

Comment: since the scope `i` of the function is a variable definition for the scope of that function, you need to pass in the reference to `i` by telling that it will pass in the number immediately do that function, so it would understand what i is.